# IBM Notes (previously Lotus Notes) exporter to maildir

Tags: email, file-converter

Is anybody aware of a means by which to export IBM Notes mail to maildir?  Ideally the source code for it would be publicly available.

I came across a python script to export IBM Notes to mbox format but I found it to be slower than I thought it needed to be -- for a number of reasons I can expand upon if requested.  What was the biggest problem for me was that each time I wanted to update the mbox it would have to start fresh.

https://code.google.com/p/nlconverter/ is the application, and don't get me wrong, it's great to have an open source Notes exporter.  I had to hack it together a bit to make it work.

I'll send the developer some of my fixes soon enough and may even be forced to expand on it myself if there's no better alternative, the developer is definitely good at what he does, it's just not supported and clearly had a single intended use.  It's a pretty wonderful codebase, it's not even hard to expand upon to make it export to Maildir, maybe I'm just lazy but there were some specifics I couldn't seem to get right.

Comment: If anybody is still interested in this, I've found a potentially easier way that one could go about importing Notes email to maildir which requires an android phone.  Within the Android application settings folder, under Notes Traveler sub-folder there's an sqlite database of all the email the client is set to download (day, week, month or all).  This may be the same for iPhone as well.
Additional options that I've found include: https://github.com/javabean/iNotes-exporter https://github.com/prenagha/notes2cloud/

Comment: Additionally, there's something called npop3.exe in Program Files\IBM but I cannot find any documentation on it.